# Medoo insert issue causing internal server error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying out the simple medoo.in php database framework.

just saving a form input into database

```
<?php
require_once 'includes/medoo.php';

$FName = $_POST["FName"];
$EMail = $_POST["EMail"];

$db = new medoo();
$db->insert("wp_discount", ["FName" => "TT","EMail" => "ROAR"]);
?>
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $FName; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $EMail; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem is with the insert line. when i remove that line everything works fine.

i get internal server error

```
Error log:

20140401T040139: www.geteasyread.com/csspure/form.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /hermes/waloraweb010/b1216/moo.skychewcom/easyread/csspure/form.php on line 8
```

but i don't see what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$db->insert("wp_discount", array("FName" => "TT","EMail" => "ROAR"));
```

short array syntax exists in php >= 5.4, maybe that's not your case